# custom vim syntax highlighting scripts-- why do they work in Windows but not Linux?

Tags: linux, vim

I have written a vim script for highlighting the syntax of a proprietary query language.  It works fine on my Windows 7 machine running gvim 7.3, but it refuses to work on Linux (my test box is CentOS 6).  I have gotten the built-in language highlight scripts to work in CentOS, but for some reason any custom syntax scripts I add to the /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax directory are not recognized even when I explicitly run

```
:set filetype=on
:set syntax=on
:set ft=cy
```

with cy.vim being the name of my syntax script.  I checked out the ftplugin scripts to see if there was anything special pointing a filetype to a syntax script, but I couldn't see anything... I have another cy.vim file there anyway which reads

```
augroup cy,Q,q
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.cy,*.Q,*.q set filetype=cy 
augroup end
```

normally I just keep the above in my _vimrc file, but as I can't even get the highlighting to work with explicit commands I doubt automatic filetype recognition on load would work.
Can anyone shed some light on why my syntax script works perfectly on Windows but not at all on Linux?  I have tried all the usual avenues already, such as making sure I have vim-common/vim-full/vim-enhanced installed rather than vim-minimal/vim-tiny.  Any help would be appreciated!

thanks,
CCJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue may have been with my xterm settings; on Solaris I ran into the same problem until I explicitly set the xterm window to support text colors and updated ncurses, per the wiki here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Getting_colors_to_work_on_solaris
I haven't been able to revisit on CentOS Linux yet, but this solved the problem for Solaris

Answer (score 3):

On Linux box vim will use ~/.vimrc and ~/.vim/.

Try the following command to see vim file type:

```
:echo &ft
```

Try the following to command see if your file is loaded:

```
:scriptnames
```

Comment: the filetype is correctly loaded as cy in my test source, and the cy.vim script is loaded... I don't see either .vimrc or .vim files in my home directory.  Should I create them explicitly?  If so, what should their content be?

Answer (score 0):

Can you load the syntax file via the full path?

```
:so /path/to/file.vim
```

What are the permissions on the syntax file?

```
ls -l /path/to/file.vim
```

Comment: hmm, this is odd... the permissions on my script are 755 and, but all the other syntax scripts are 644.  Could that mean VIM/Linux is misinterpreting the intended use of the vim script file?  I tried modding the permissions to 644, but it still wouldn't work...

Comment: How exactly would I load the syntax file via the full path?  Is there a VIM command to explicitly load syntax files without involving filetype?